# write a jpeg with libjpeg (seg fault)

Tags: c, linux, libjpeg

Trying to write a jpeg file from some raw data using libjpeg.

It triggers a Segmentation Fault in `jpeg_start_compress()`

Here is the relevant part of the code :

```
void write_sub_image(char *filename, int start, int end)
{
    struct jpeg_compress_struct cinfo;
    unsigned char *stride;
    JSAMPROW row_pointer[1];
    unsigned long new_width = end-start;
    int i;
    FILE *fp;

    stride = (unsigned char *)malloc( new_width * 3);

    fp = fopen(filename, "w+");

    jpeg_create_compress(&cinfo);

    jpeg_stdio_dest(&cinfo, fp);

    cinfo.image_width = new_width;
    cinfo.image_height = height;
    cinfo.input_components = 3;
    cinfo.in_color_space = JCS_RGB;

    jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);

    jpeg_start_compress(&cinfo, FALSE);

    for (i=0; i<height; i++) {
        memcpy (stride, image + (start + i * width) * 3, new_width * 3);
        row_pointer[0] = stride;
        jpeg_write_scanlines(&cinfo, &stride, 1);
    }

    jpeg_finish_compress(&cinfo);
    jpeg_destroy_compress(&cinfo);

    fclose(fp);
}
```

The problem is not with the memcpy, it does not even get to the for loop... just crash at _start_compress.

In case that is relevant, the system is Ubuntu 10.10.

Comment: Have you checked that `new_width` and `height` are valid (i.e. > 0)?

Comment: In fact, that can't be the whole code, as `height` isn't declared.

Comment: it's declared outside, this is part of a larger code but should be a piece that can work by itself. I checked and new_width=96 and height=200 in my test.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to set an error manager:

```
struct jpeg_error_mgr jerr; 
....
cinfo.err = jpeg_std_error(&jerr); 
jpeg_set_defaults(&cinfo);
....
```

Comment: worked perfect... for some reason it was not there in the example I got the code from.