# RGB888 (24 bit) to PNG/JPEG image algorithm

Tags: c, png, jpeg, rgb, image-conversion

I need to convert 24 bit RGB(888) image data to PNG or JPEG image (whichever possible). Need simpler approach to do this same like converting RGB888 to BMP without any compression. Would be great if it is something like adding PNG/JPEG headers to the RGB data with/without little modification. Ready to provide more details on request..

Thanks in advance..

Language/Platform : C/Linux

Comment: [Write a jpeg with libjpeg](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4664087/write-a-jpeg-with-libjpeg-seg-fault) - Helpful?

Comment: It is not possible to create a JPEG image by "adding JPEG headers to the RGB data with little modification". Check `libjpeg` (reference JPEG encoder and decoder implementation in C) for converting RGB to JPEG.

Comment: Thanks Roman R & Simon, I will check with libjpeg for jpeg conversion. Can anybody help me out in RGB888 tp PNG conversion as requested earlier..

Comment: try maybe libpng? First hit on google.

Comment: Thanks Art, I will look into libpng too. Meanwhile can anyone gimme idea on doing this conversion RGB888 to PNG manually without using any library (as compression is not needed).

Comment: PNG uses compression, you must use libpng or similar library

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [miniz](http://code.google.com/p/miniz/) - a.k.a single C source file Deflate/Inflate compression library with zlib-compatible API, ZIP archive reading/writing, PNG writing.

Answer (score 1):

If you just need an image format then the easiest is probably [ppm](http://netpbm.sourceforge.net/doc/ppm.html) (or pgm for greyscale)

You just need to add a small ascii header to the uncompressed binary data and most image apps will read it.

```
P6   <-- magic value for binary data
# a comment if you want
640 480    <-- width x height
255      <-- max pixel value
.... binary data here .......
```

Comment: @leonbloy - yes, the nice thing about pgm/ppm is you can write the header with an editor. If your editor can handle binary you casn even edit as raw memory dump into an imag